# Does 'nonlocal' variable always inherit from the outer loop, even in recursive calls?

Tags: python, recursion, python-nonlocal

I have written some code and recently came across the need for 'nonlocal' when writing functions of functions (came across this when dealing with recursion).

For example:

```
def swapPairs(head): 
    head = None

    def helper(node): 
        nonlocal head 
        ...
        head= nex.next 
        return helper(node.next)
```

My question is quite simple, as we call the recursion function `helper(node.next)` , and loop back up to `nonlocal head` - does `head` take the value of None (due to nonlocal head)? Or does it retain `head = nex.next`, which it was assigned to in the previous recursion call?

So I am trying to understand whether `'nonlocal head'` would cause `head` to always take the value of whatever it was assigned to in the outer function, or is this not the case? And instead it is just a way to initialise head in the inner function so it only STARTS by taking the initial value as defined in the outer function.

Comment: `nonlocal` *only* changes how the name `head` is understood while compiling the rest of the code. There is no compiled code representing the statement itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nonlocal` and `global` declarations are for *lexical* scoping – loosely speaking, they only care about the source code layout.

```py
def swapPairs(head): 
    head = None         # `head` in lexically outer scope          <═╗
                        #                                            ║
    def helper(node):   #                                            ║
        nonlocal head   # nonlocal `head` for inner lexical scope  >═╣
        ...             #                                            ║
        head= nex.next  # nonlocal applies to every use            >═╝
        return helper(node.next)
```

Notably, scoping is not at all concerned with the runtime nesting of the code; it does not care whether `helper` is called by `swapPairs`, a sequence of `helper`s, or some unrelated function:   The name `head` inside `helper` is completely equivalent to the name `head` inside `swapPairs`.

That means the `head` inside `def helper` will *always* refer to the `head` inside the `swapPairs` call that defined `def helper`. Once the first call to `helper` assigns `head = nex.next` that changes the `head` *inside the `swapPairs`* and subsequent calls to `helper` will see (and modify) this new value.

Comment: Thanks Mister, great explanation. But just to confirm I understand this correctly, when we call helper(node.next) say on the first recursion call, as we run through the helper() function, head=nex.next and NOT head=None. Is this correct?

Comment: I do understand what you mean by "the head inside def helper will always refer to the head inside the swapPairs" - however, after the first head=None call in swapPairs, we DO NOT visit/call swapPairs anymore. So I wanted to confirm head=None will NOT ever be reached.

Comment: @PatrickChong Indeed, unless ``helper`` (or any other function that captured ``head``) assigns ``head = None``, it won't turn back to ``None``. The ``head = None`` inside ``swapPairs`` is still just a regular statement that is executed in the usual order, and doesn't get implicitly rerun later on.